# Checking a users custom claims (is an admin) on login with React, Redux and Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

I was wondering if someone could help me.

I am currently building an admin dashboard, which can only be accessed by admins. I am using React, Redux and Firebase.

I have managed to set custom claims on specific users in a cloud function like so:

```
exports.addSuperAdminRole = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email).then(user => {
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
      superAdmin: true
    })
  }).then(() => {
    return {
      message: `Success! ${data.email} has been made an admin.`
    }
  }).catch(err => {
    return err;
  });
});
```

I would now like restrict access to the dashboard for superAdmins only, and was wondering what was the best (most secure) way to do this.

Currently I have the following client side login action working where I check the custom claim and just log the user back out if they are not an admin:

```
export const login = creds => {
  return async (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase }) => {
    const firebase = getFirebase();
    try {
      await firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(creds.email, creds.password);

        const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        currentUser.getIdTokenResult().then(idTokenResult => {
          console.log(currentUser);
          currentUser.superAdmin = idTokenResult.claims.superAdmin;

          if (!currentUser.superAdmin) {
            console.log('is not admin');
            firebase.logout();
          }
        });

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw new SubmissionError({
        _error: 'Login failed'
      });
    }
  };
};
```

Is this sufficient or do I need to run a cloud function on login, check the claims, then logout the user? If so how would do this?

Any help you could give me would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

James

Comment: Try to have a look at this: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/02/01/react-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example i think its what you are looking for.

Comment: Refer https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

Answer (score 1):

Note that, in any case, what is the most important is that you correctly secured your database **with security rules that incorporate the `superAdmin` claim**.

As a matter of fact, anybody who knows the URL of your admin dashboard can easily get your Firebase configuration (even if they are not logged in, as this config object is embedded in the js files of your app). Then they can implement their own web page which calls the `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` method **without being logged out**.

In other words, you should not waste extra time "protecting" your dashboard web app, which should be considered as a simple "user interface" that displays data from your database. **It is THE database that you need to protect.**

**Conclusion**: hiding the admin dashboard pages (or the admin menu items, and/or the admin buttons), based on the claims (i.e. "modifying the client UI based on the user's role or access level", as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#access_custom_claims_on_the_client)) is sufficient, **knowing that your database is correctly protected**.

Comment: Hi Renaud thanks for getting back to me - I will ensure I add the necessary rules to protect the db properly. I just wanted to ensure that a non-admin user could not get past the login form and that I had sufficiently done this.

Comment: Yes, I do understand :-) I don't know react but it seems that you indeed correctly log out the user if he/she doesn't have the correct Custom Claims. But my point was to explain that, in the light of your functional requirements, all you are going to do in the front end (like this auto log out) is just going to either increase the user friendliness of your application or hide away some of its features **but will not secure it**.

Answer (score 1):

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';  // this works with npm install firebase


firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
  .then((idTokenResult) => {
     // Confirm the user is an Admin.
     if (!!idTokenResult.claims.admin) {
       // Show admin UI.
       showAdminUI();
     } else {
       // Show regular user UI.
       showRegularUI();
     }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Resource : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

Answer (score 0):

Checking custom claims in client code is not secure, since client code can always be compromised to do whatever an attacker wants.  If you want to be truly secure, you will have to also check claims in security rules and any backend code that operates on the user's behalf.

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks for your response. 

Is it possible to have different rules for my admin dashboard (admin.myurl.com) than the main site (myurl.com)? 

I am unsure how I can restrict access to the admin dashboard, without effecting the main site

Comment: That sounds like it should be posted as a separate question.