# Firebase - different rules for multiple hosting sites within the same Firebase project

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Is it possible to have different rules for my admin dashboard (admin.myurl.com) than the main site (myurl.com)? Both sites will be hosted within the same firebase project.

I am looking to create an admin dashboard where admin users (users with custom claim of superAdmin) can CRUD posts & events etc on the site.

Non-admin users will also be able to create and edit events on the main site, but not posts, so i need to add different rules to the admin dashboard to stop non-admins from accessing it!

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following security rules for that:

```
function signedInAdmin() {
  return signedIn() && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin == true;
}

function signedIn() {
  return request.auth.uid != null;
}

match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write, update, create: if signedInAdmin();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one set of rules per product per project.  If you have two sites connected to the same project, they will both have the same set of rules applied to their users.

If you need to have different rules for different users, you will have to figure out how to designate roles for your users to determine what sort of access they should have to the database.

If you're using Cloud Firestore as the database, get acquainted with [authentication based rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication).  Similar documentation for Realtime Database is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security#section-authentication).

Comment: Hi Doug, thks for responding to me (again). From research & Orons answer I get that I need to lock down what users get what access to the db. My question is a continuation of the one I asked a few days ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58133041/checking-a-users-custom-claims-is-an-admin-on-login-with-react-redux-and-fire

If the main site allows any user to create events and I allow this in the database rules, how can I stop this user from accessing the admin dashboard (where events can also be created)? This is why I tried to add a login form that checks if the user is an admin